# mvvm light calling RaisePropertyChanged doesn't fire Property getter(windows phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, mvvm-light

in my application I have a textbox that user type a number on it. I want to this Latin number to Persian one as user type it. after calling `RaisePropertychanged` the `getter` of `MobileNumber` not called so App Ui doesn't update. what is the problem with my code?

here is my code

### View.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="CustomName.RegistrationPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ShahrMobileBank.Views.Masters.Registration"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:converter="using:ShahrMobileBank.Converter"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding Path=RegistrationPage, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

    <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource RegistrationPageBackgroundColor}" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <converter:RegistrationConverter x:Key="RegistrationConverter"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource GenericTextBoxBeforeLogin}"  x:Uid="PhoneNumber" InputScope="Number" Text="{Binding Path=MobileNumber,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="{StaticResource MobileNumberMaxLength}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

### ViewModel.cs

```
public class RegistrationPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _mobileNumber;

    public String MobileNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _mobileNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _mobileNumber = LangUtil.ConvertEnNumberToFaNumber(value); // this converts the number from Latin to Persian
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MobileNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to use: `Set( ref _mobileNumber , LangUtil.ConvertEnNumberToFaNumber(value))` ?

Comment: The property is not updated until the user leaves the textbox.  Are you expecting the property value to change as the user types?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `RaisePropertyChanged` line to `RaisePropertyChanged("MobileNumber");`

If you use the MVVM-Light Code snippets (if installed, you can start typing mvvm, and intellisense will pop up), you can look at `mvvmpinpc`which is one of the `PropertyChanged` code snippets. You can `Tab` through the different template fields to set it up to what you want, as well as possibly shed any light on little tips and tricks to make your coding life easier.